# Decode percent escaped string inside NSXMLParser delegate method

Tags: objective-c, ios, escaping, nsxmlparser

i'm getting a UTF8 encoded data from a server data is like `Less%20than%20100` but i need this data in `Less than 100` (decoded format),my NSXMLParsing delegate method is like

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
if([elementName isEqualToString:@"option"]) {

            dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
            [dict setValue:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"text"] forKey:@"text"];/* Here itself i need to decode & save in to my dict */
}
```

How to decode this data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you have decoded your xml, use `stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method on `NSString` :

```
NSString *decoded = [text stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

See the [docs here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html).